# Play video in android device from PHP server?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am developing a **school application** and I want to play video from my PHP server

I have tried this code but it couldn't play

`Uri video = Uri.fromFile(myurl);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);                   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
intent.setDataAndType(video, "video/*");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one, play the video on vedio view through the parse the uri

xml part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Now java part

```
 public class HelloInterruptVideoStream extends Activity
{
    private String path = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/145894/t/rabbits.3gp";
    private VideoView videoview;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        videoview = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        videoview.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.start();
    }
}
```

Use internet permission in menifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: i do the same thing but i got 08-12 15:02:53.424: D/MediaPlayer(7164): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
08-12 15:02:55.639: E/MediaPlayer(7164): error (1, -2147483648)
08-12 15:02:55.640: E/MediaPlayer(7164): Error (1,-2147483648)
08-12 15:02:55.640: D/VideoView(7164): Error: 1,-2147483648 error

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your `MediaController` in this way:

```
MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);

mediaController.setAnchorView(video);  
videoview.setMediaController(mediaController);
```